# Replacing _.each in a function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this snippet that counts the number rows and returns the number of rows found in a MySQL table. This is the code, in which I have used underscore.js's `_.each` to iterate.

```
var all_rows = Noder.query('SELECT count(*) as erow from crud ', function(err, the_rows) {

            _.each(the_rows, function (corndog) {
            var trows = corndog.erow;
            console.log("All rows", trows);
            });

            // var das_rows = trows;
            // var total_pages = Math.ceil(das_rows / per_page);
            // console.log("Pages",total_pages);

         res.view('noder/orm', {
            layout: 'layout',
            js:the_rows,
            post:results,
            title: 'This is the hi page title. Gandalf The great.'
        });
        });
```

I want to use `trows` to calculate the number of pages are to be created for my paging code. However, I cannot access the variable `trows`.

This is the output of `console.log(the_rows);`

```
[ RowDataPacket { erow: 12 } ]
```

Is there another way I can do this to make `trows` available to the rest of my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `var trows` only exists inside of the iterator, as that `function` creates its own scope to contain variables.

```
function (corndog) {
    var trows = corndog.erow;
    console.log("All rows",trows);
} // `trows` is removed from existence at this point

console.log(trows); // ReferencError
```

But, the `function` does have access to variables in surrounding scopes. So, you can declare `trows` outside of the function, then assign it inside.

```
var trows;

_.each(the_rows, function (corndog) {
    trows = corndog.erow; // note removal of `var`
    console.log("All rows",trows);
});

console.log(trows); // 12
```

---

Though, `_.each()` isn't really necessary when you're only wanting a single value. You can access a particular index of the collection and chain onto that the property you're after:

```
var trows = the_rows[0].erow;
```

If there's concern about `the_rows` being empty, you can [test for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to avoid errors with `undefined`:

```
var trows = the_rows.length ? the_rows[0].erow : null;
```

---

Side note: Be sure to always test for an `err`. If one occurs, `the_rows` will likely be `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand what you're asking - but

```
var allTrows = [];
_.each(the_rows, function (corndog) {
        var trows = corndog.erow;
        console.log("All rows",trows);
         allTrows.push (trows);
});
```

Then return allTrows in your res.render.

Answer (score 1):

While Jonathan and Ilya have already given practical solutions to your specific problem, let me provide a generic answer to the question in the title:

The simplest way to replace `_.each()` is to iterate over the array using a plain [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < the_rows.length; i++) {
    var row = the_rows[i];
    console.log( "In loop: row = the_rows[" + i + "] =", row );
}
console.log( "After loop: row =", row );
```

or, in ES6 or later, a [`for`...`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
for (var row of the_rows) {
    console.log( "In loop: row =", row );
}
console.log( "After loop: row =", row );
```

(You *could* also use a [`for`...`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, but [you probably shouldn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea))

Since these are built-in looping constructs, and do not involve an inner function like `_.each()` does, any variables defined in them will retain their last value after the loop ends.

---

Another way to replace `_.each` is using the built-in [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method of JS arrays:

```
the_rows.forEach( function (row, i) {
    console.log( "In loop: row = the_rows[" + i + "] =", row );
} );
```

or, if you want to use this method to loop over something that looks like an array but isn't actually one (such as, say, a DOM [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( the_rows, function (row, i) {
    console.log( "In loop: row = the_rows[" + i + "] =", row );
} );
```

However, since `.forEach()` does require wrapping the loop body in an inner function, just like `_.each()`, any variables declared using `var` inside it will not be available outside the loop.  However, variables declared outside the loop function *are* visible inside in it, so you can do e.g. this:

```
var last_row;
the_rows.forEach( function (row, i) {
    last_row = row;  // <-- no "var"!
    console.log( "In loop: last_row = row = the_rows[" + i + "] =", row );
} );
console.log( "After loop: last_row =", last_row );
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `trows` outside of the loop:

```
var trows = 0;
_.each(the_rows, function (corndog) {
    trows += corndog.erow;
    console.log("All rows",trows);
});
```